# How are you populating/validating your ViewModels?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, viewmodel

I'm curious of all of the various ways people are building their ViewModels and why they choose that method.

I can think of several ways here:

-1. Injected repository - the controller loads the model and maps to the ViewModel. Here the ViewModel constructor could take various collections to interally set for ex. in a select list such as:

```
public CustomerController(ISomeRepository repository)
{
   _repository = repository;
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
  CustomerCreateViewModel model = new CustomerCreateViewModel(_repository.GetShipTypes, 
                                                                _repository.GetStates);
..
..
}
```

-2. ViewModelBuilder - Either injected or instantiated in the controller with an instance of the injected repository. Called via something like

```
>var orderViewModel = orderViewModelBuilder.WithStates().Build(orderId);
```

or,

```
var orderViewModel = orderViewModelBuilder.WithStates().Build(orderId);
```

-3. Directly in controller (no code required - its messy)

-4. Some other service (injected or not) that returns domain model which the controller then maps or a ViewModel (anyone doing this to return a view model that isn't specifically named/noted as a ViewModel builder class?)

```
public JobCreateViewModel BuildJobCreateViewModel(int parentId)
{
   JobCreateViewModel model = new JobCreateViewModel();
   model.JobStatus = _unitOfWork.JobRepository.GetJobStatuses();
   model.States=_unitOfWork.StateRepository.GetAll();
   return model;
}
```

Now on the return trip - regarding validating your view models - are you inheriting from a base ViewModel class for standard validations, or copying your validations (ex. data annotation attributes) between all of your ViewModels, or simply relying on server side validation so it can all be validated againt your domain object?

Any others? Anything better? Why?

**EDIT**
Based on a link below, I did find a nice article from Jimmy Bogard on the architecture of ViewModels. While it doesn't address the question above directly, it's a great reference for anyone coming here for ViewModel information.
http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/

Comment: there was a downvote on here - just curious why - anything I can clarify?

Comment: On my phone and I inadvertently clicked it while trying to star -- sorry.  Now it's too late to undo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I inject a service into the controller, not a repository, and then use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to convert it into a view model. The benefit of the service layer in this case is that it could aggregate multiple simple operations from one or more repositories into a single operation exposing a domain model. Example:

```
private readonly ICustomerService _service;
public CustomerController(ICustomerService service)
{
    _service = service;
}

[AutoMap(typeof(Customer), typeof(CustomerViewModel))]
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    Customer customer = _service.GetCustomer(id);
    return View(customer);
}
```

in this example AutoMap is a custom action filter that I can write which executes after the controller action, inspects the returned object and uses defined AutoMapper mappings to map it to the specified destination type. So the view gets the corresponding CustomerViewModel as model type. Would have been equivalent to:

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
    Customer customer = _service.GetCustomer(id);
    CustomerViewModel vm = Mapper.Map<Customer, CustomerViewModel>(customer);
    return View(vm);
}
```

it's just that it is too much plumbing and repetitive code that could be centralized.

I would also recommend you watching the [*putting your controllers on a diet video*](http://www.viddler.com/explore/mvcconf/videos/1/) from Jimmy Bogard.

Comment: Thanks Darin. I watched someone demo a similar AutoMap attribute - I see Jimmy has one available. What do you do for client validation of these view models (or don't you?) and sharing validation logic between them? Are you then injecting your repositories into your service layer?

Comment: @AdamTuliper, I use FluentValidation.NET for server side validation and for simple client side validation scenarios (required, date greater than, ...). For more complex client side validation scenarios (dependent properties, ...) I decide whether I need to handle it on the client and if there is a requirement to perform client side validation for those scenarios I write custom jquery validate appenders. As far as repositories into the service layer are concerned, yes the service layer uses ctor injection to have all the repositories allowing to perform simple CRUD operations on domain models.

Comment: Thanks Darin, another fine answer : )

Comment: As I look over the above, one question comes to mind. When your model needs to contain a list, for instance IEnumerable<State>, how are you handling this mapping to a drop down list from a Customer domain object? If we're using entity framework, I can see Customer.States being defined in your view model but it seems that in mapping the id back to the entity the fields wouldn't jive if you need for. ex StateId  - So your ViewModel needs a collection of States but the actual Entity has only StateId. It would seem here we can't use a nice automap attribute?

Comment: @AdamTuliper, indeed in this case an `AutoMap` attribute wouldn't work as the view model will be composed of 2 aggregate roots (a customer and a list of states). So we define a mapping for each of those two aggregate roots so that they are mapped to their corresponding view models for the given view and finally the two view models are aggregated into the final view model passed to the view.

Comment: @Darin, do you have an `[AutoMap]` for post actions?

Comment: I like the `service` solution but I find this example a little too simplistic. In a real case you will need to return not just a customer object but some other stuff like products or categories or whatever. What is your approach in this case? Do you create a specific service method that returns a more complex model ready to get flattened to a ViewModel for that specific view?

Answer (score 1):

I just finished a project where we did a variation on #4.  We had a service class injected into the controller.  The service class held dependencies on the repository and a model builder class (we called it model factory).

The controller called into the service class, which handled business validation logic, and then fetched view models from the appropriate factory.  The models themselves relied on data annotations for input validation.

It worked really well for our team.  There was enough separation of concerns to allow the devs to do their work without affecting one another, but it was manageable enough to understand what was going on.

It's the first time we tried it and we'll be sticking with it.  I'm interested to see how others respond.

Comment: thanks. So your service class was in turn injected with the repository? What were your methods setup like for ex. in the service class? How did you handle client side validation across multiple but similar view models? (ex. edit vs. create)

Comment: it's very similar to Darin's example below, we had a crazy requirement that we couldn't use open source software, so we couldn't use Automapper.  Next time we will replace the view model factory with automapper.  We used Display and Editor templates to serve the different views of the same model, the data annotation provided us with all of the validation we needed.

Comment: And the model builder class receive repository object from an constructor parameter (service handle the repository object) or model builder directly used the repository itself ? Can you please provide some very simple example ?

Answer (score 0):

Our method is to inject the repository in to the controller and map it to the ViewModel using Automapper http://automapper.org/.  Our ViewModels contain data annotation attributes to allow the validation to occur on the client.

We call methods on the repository which return Domain objects (Entity Framework). The domain objects are mapped to the ViewModel.  We tend to use the same ViewModel for edits and adds so the data annotations are needed once.   In its simplest form it looks like the following code:

```
    public ActionResult List(int custId, int projId)
    {
        var users = _userRepository.GetByCustomerId(custId);
        var userList = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CMUser>, IEnumerable<UserListViewModel>>(users);
        return View(userList);
    }
```

Comment: but a repository isn't mapped to a view model. Some method must be called in the repository to either return a domain object or a viewmodel. Also this doesn't cover if you use separate annotations for each model or a shared location, etc.

Comment: Also if using the same ViewModel for edits/adds then what are you doing to about an integer ID field being required by default with data annotations? If missing from the form, it will fail validaton. Ints are required by default so you would have to initialize to 0 for the "create" scenario, no?

Answer (score 0):

I use a service layer that hides the domain model from the controller returning ViewModels from the service methods. This allows me to make changes to the domain model without impacting the client.